# How to define Python functions inside a loop and use *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, closures, args, keyword-argument, late-binding

I'm trying to print a message when instance methods get called, like below. I'm running into [this problem](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures), but I'm having trouble solving it in my case because all the solutions seem to require passing in specific arguments which I can't do here.

```
class MathLab:
    def add(self, a, b):
        print(a + b)

    def mult(self, a, b):
        print(a * b)


m = MathLab()

for method in [m.add, m.mult]:
    def tracked_method(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Running: " + method.__name__)
        method(*args, **kwargs)


    m.__setattr__(method.__name__, tracked_method)

m.add(5, 5)
```

Output

```
Running: mult
25
```

Comment: I'm gonna _guess_ that you're after a decorator, given your previous question also.

Comment: @roganjosh Hi again :) Yeah this question is tangentially related... I'm writing a helper function that will print the name of dunder methods on a DataFrame as they're called so I can try to figure out if there's one that gets called on every update which I can then override. If I can't figure it out I may try asking again

Comment: :) I think you'll really struggle. What you're suggesting (in my head) is that you want to free-wheel this stuff without creating an API. Tagging on to _every_ method - why would you want to log that if you weren't trying to control something?

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah I'd use a decorator if I was writing my own class, but right now I'm just trying to monkey patch a DataFrame's methods so it tells me what dunder methods run when I modify it. Then I can monkey patch those dunder methods to print a statement notifying the user when it's modified. I know all this monkey patching seems very dirty but if you have another solution to my first question I welcome it!

Comment: What about `groupby`? That's Cython code and pretty common - does that even call a dunder that you can trace?

Comment: @roganjosh `groupby` isn't one of the methods that could modify a `DataFrame`, it doesn't have an `inplace` argument (and couldn't, because it returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` object not a `DataFrame`)

Comment: it's asking me to invite you to chat. Instead of that, I already raised this in the [python room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and you are welcome to join me there. If there are people to figure this out, they'll probably be there, but we should be concise on exactly what you want (I've already linked to this question in that room earlier on to see if anyone was interested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help? Add a keyword argument with a default value in order to do early binding of `method` (then use that keyword argument `_method` in place of `method` inside the function).

The whole code is shown for convenience, but the only part changed from the code in the question is the `tracked_method` function itself.

```
class MathLab:
    def add(self, a, b):
        print(a + b)

    def mult(self, a, b):
        print(a * b)


m = MathLab()

for method in [m.add, m.mult]:
    def tracked_method(*args, _method=method, **kwargs):
        print("Running: " + _method.__name__)
        _method(*args, **kwargs)


    m.__setattr__(method.__name__, tracked_method)

m.add(5, 5)
```

Gives:

```
Running: add
10
```

By the way, instead of using `m.__setattr__(...)`, you could simply use `setattr(m, ...)`.